# Cannot resolve keyword 'username' into field. Choices are: address, age, city, country, gender, name, phone, pt_id, user, user_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Please help me, I am stuck at this error. I am new to django, I don't know how to solve this errorstrong text
**patients/views.py**

```
@method_decorator([login_required, patient_required], name='dispatch')
    class EditPatient(UpdateView):
        model = Patient_Profile
        fields = ['pt_id', 'name', 'gender', 'age', 'phone', 'address', 'city', 'country']
        template_name = 'patient/patient_edit.html'
        slug_field = 'username'
        slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('patients:patient_page')
    
        def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
            context = super(EditPatient, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
            return context
```

**patients/models.py**

```
class Patient_Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    pt_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.TextField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**patients/urls.py**

```
app_name = 'patients'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.patient_page, name='patient_home'),
    path('profile/<slug>', views.EditPatient.as_view(), name='profile'),
]
```

**template**

```
<h1>I am {{user.username}} </h1>
<a href="{% url 'patients:profile' slug=user.slug %}">Edit Patient</a>
{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you or working with the `Profile`, you should filter on the `user__username` since we are filtering the `username` field of the `user` of the `Profile`, so:

```
@method_decorator([login_required, patient_required], name='dispatch')
class EditPatient(UpdateView):
    # …
    slug_field = 'user__username'
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: When working with class-based views, *mixins* are often preferred over decorators. For the `@login_required` decorator
> the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)
> can be used.

Answer (score 0):

there is no `username` field in `Patient_Profile` table.

use `user__username` it instead:

```
@method_decorator([login_required, patient_required], name='dispatch')
class EditPatient(UpdateView):
    # …
    slug_field = 'user__username'
    # …
```